# Apple ITunes AppStore Customer Review rss endpoint not working

Tags: rss, app-store-connect

The Itunes CustomerReivew rss endpoint that worked well does not work from two days ago. I would like to continue with `xml` type. What should I do? Typing `json` instead of `xml` works fine.

[check this out.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=appId/sortBy=mostRecent/xml)

Answer (score 2):

The only extra column that you receive from `xml` (that's not in `json`) is the date. If you don't need that one, it's better to stick to `json` as there doesn't seem to be any information about when `xml` feed would be available.

Working link: https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/customerreviews/page=2/id=742044692/sortby=mostrecent/json

Comment: I don't know when it was added but the json result includes the date now.